# Drawing in JPanel disappears when scrolling or ressizing the frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, java-2d

I have a big problem that I can't solve it I have a `JPanel` in a `JFrame`. In this panel I draw many things (like a diagram) it works, but when I scroll the panel or when I resize the frame the drawings disappears!

How should I get the drawing to remain?

The code:

```
  private void full_simulation_button(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

   if (jTextField1.getText().equals("")){
  JOptionPane jop2 = new JOptionPane();
  jop2.showMessageDialog(null, "You should enter you trace file !",         "Attention", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
   else {

  Graphics g = jPanel5.getGraphics();  

g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawRect(150,10,100,20);  
g.fillRect(150,10,100,20);
g.drawLine(200,10 , 200, 2000);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("UE",190 ,25 );

g.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
g.drawRect(350,10,100,20); 
g.fillRect(350,10,100,20);
g.drawLine(400,10 , 400, 2000);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("Node B",380 ,25 );

 g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.drawRect(550,10,100,20);    
g.fillRect(550,10,100,20);
g.drawLine(600,10 , 600, 2000);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("RNC",590 ,25 );

g.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
g.drawRect(750,10,100,20);    
g.fillRect(750,10,100,20);
g.drawLine(800,10 , 800, 2000);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("CN",790 ,25 );

System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
try {
     final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();      
     final Document document= builder.parse(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
     //Affiche la version de XML
     System.out.println("la version du XML est "+ document.getXmlVersion());
    //Affiche l'encodage
    System.out.println("l'encodage utilisé est"+document.getXmlEncoding()); 
    //Affiche s'il s'agit d'un document standalone      
    System.out.println("le document est standolone:"+document.getXmlStandalone());

    final Element racine = document.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println("le racime du fichier est :"+racine.getNodeName());

    final NodeList racineNoeuds = racine.getChildNodes();

    final int nbRacineNoeuds = racineNoeuds.getLength();

    for (int i = 0; i<nbRacineNoeuds; i++) {
          if(racineNoeuds.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 final Element nd = (Element) racineNoeuds.item(i);
                 final Node noeud = racineNoeuds.item(i);
                 System.out.println(noeud.getNodeName());



    final NodeList msg = nd.getElementsByTagName("PARA");
    final int nbre = msg.getLength();
    int marge=0;
    int rang =1;
    String type =null;
    String direction=null;
    for(int j = 0; j<nbre ; j++){

        final Element message = (Element) msg.item(j);


        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if ( message.getAttribute("name").equals("Message Type")){ 
        type = message.getAttribute("value");
       // System.out.println(type);
        if (type.startsWith("RRC")){

          g.drawLine(200,50+marge , 600, 50+marge);
          g.drawString(rang+". "+type,220 ,45+marge );
          marge=marge+30;
          rang=rang+1; 
         }
        if (type.startsWith("NBAP")){
          g.drawLine(400,50+marge , 600, 50+marge);
          g.drawString(rang+". "+type,420 ,45+marge );
          marge=marge+30;
          rang=rang+1; 

         }
        if (type.startsWith("RANAP")){
            g.drawLine(600,50+marge , 800, 50+marge);
            g.drawString(rang+". "+type,620 ,45+marge );
            marge=marge+30;
            rang=rang+1; 

         }
        }
        if ( message.getAttribute("name").equals("Message Direction")){ 
        direction = message.getAttribute("value");
        //System.out.println(direction);
        if ((direction.equals("From-UE"))&&(type.startsWith("RRC"))){
          g.drawString(">",595, 50+marge-25 );
          System.out.println(type);

         }
        if ((direction.equals("To-UE"))&&(type.startsWith("RRC"))){
          g.drawString("<",200, 50+marge-25 );
          System.out.println(type);

         }
        if ((direction.equals("From-NodeB"))&&(type.startsWith("NBAP"))){
          g.drawString(">",595, 50+marge-25 );
          System.out.println(type);

         }
        if ((direction.equals("To-NodeB"))&&(type.startsWith("NBAP"))){
          g.drawString("<",400, 50+marge-25 );
          System.out.println(type);

         }
        if ((direction.equals("From-CN"))&&(type.startsWith("RANAP"))){
          g.drawString("<",600, 50+marge-25 );
          System.out.println(type);

         }
        if ((direction.equals("To-CN"))&&(type.startsWith("RANAP"))){
          g.drawString(">",795, 50+marge-25 );
          System.out.println(type);

         }
  }

}
         }   

}

}

        catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (final SAXException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
           }
       catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
           }
          }
```

Comment: `Graphics g = jPanel5.getGraphics(); `  That's the root of the problem.  A component should paint *when it is requested to do so.*  See the [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) lesson of the tutorial for details of the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should never paint outside of the provided swing functions like `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. When resizing or scrolling the component will be repainted. In this process the `paintComponent` method of every involved component is called. Since your drawing happens outside of it, the panel is not redrawn as intended.  Override the `paintComponent` method and copy all your drawing code into it.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(150,10,100,20);  
        g.fillRect(150,10,100,20);
        g.drawLine(200,10 , 200, 2000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("UE",190 ,25 );
        /* ... All drawing code ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me where I add this code ( class MyPanel extends JPanel
     {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
   super.paintComponent(g); this is my first time to developp with java

Comment: Put it in the code of `jPanel5`.  In the `full_simulation_button` method, call `jPanel5.repaint()` ..

Comment: Now I have no thing asa result :(

Comment: 1+, custom painting by overriding paintComponent() is the way to go. You also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a size to that the panel can be displayed properly. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working example that you can play will to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you resize you component or move it in a scrollpane, it is redrawn. It's the way Swing works. If you want you panel to be able to redraw its content, it has to know about it.
In this kind of situation, you should create a new class that extends the `JComponent` class and override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. It's this method that will be responsible to draw your diagram.

```
public class Drawer extends JComponent {

    private File source;

    public void setSource(File source) {
        this.source = source;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (source == null) {
            return;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(150, 10, 100, 20);
        g.fillRect(150, 10, 100, 20);
        g.drawLine(200, 10, 200, 2000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("UE", 190, 25);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(350, 10, 100, 20);
        g.fillRect(350, 10, 100, 20);
        g.drawLine(400, 10, 400, 2000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Node B", 380, 25);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(550, 10, 100, 20);
        g.fillRect(550, 10, 100, 20);
        g.drawLine(600, 10, 600, 2000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("RNC", 590, 25);

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawRect(750, 10, 100, 20);
        g.fillRect(750, 10, 100, 20);
        g.drawLine(800, 10, 800, 2000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("CN", 790, 25);

        System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());
        final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {
            final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            final Document document = builder.parse(source);


        } catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Replace your JPanel by an instance of the Drawer class and replace the content of the listener method by:

```
private void full_simulation_button(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    if (jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You should enter you trace file !", "Attention", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        drawer.setSource(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the button, a file is created and is given as the source of the `Drawer`. The `Drawer` repaints itself and the `paintComponent()` method is called by the internal mechanism of Swing.

Now you should try to improve the code by not parsing the XML file each time the `paintComponent()` method is called (you parse it in the `setSource()` and then you use the data in the `paintComponent()`).

Comment: `final Document document = builder.parse(source);`  This is not the type of (potentially long running) task that should be in any `paint..(Graphics)` method.  And certainly not *each time* the method is called!  Instead you might declare `final Document document` as a (non final) class attribute and parse in the `setSource` method (though that might logically change the name of the method to ..`parseSource`?).

Comment: It's what I explain at the end of the post. He should improve the class to avoid parsing the file at each call. But reading that last sentence, I see it isn't clear. I changed it to be more precise.

Comment: the problem that my drawings are proprotional to the parse of the file I can't seperate them :(

Comment: As said by Andrew Thompson, you can keep the `Document` instance as a member of the class. You parse when you call `setSource`, it creates a `Document` and in the `paintComponent` method, you read the document in order to draw.

Comment: Another solution would be to paint in a BufferedImage when parsing and to draw the image in the `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: that's what I am trying to do ybanen